# Are materialized views in redshift worth their costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, materialized-views

I'm working on a project in aws redshift with a few billion rows where the main queries are rollups on time units.  The current implementation has mvs for all these rollups.  It seems to me that if redshift is all it's cracked up to be and the dist and sort keys are defined correctly the mvs should not be necessary and their costs in extra storage and maintenance (refresh).  I'm wondering if anyone has analyzed this in a similar application.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking along the right path but the real world doesn't always allow for 'just do it better'.

You are correct that sometimes MVs are just used to forego the effort of optimizing a complex query but sometimes not.  The selection of keys, especially distribution key, is a compromise between optimizing different workloads.  Distribute one way and query A gets faster but query B gets slower.  But if the results of query B don't need to be completely up to date, one can make an MV out of B and only pay the price on refresh.

Sometimes queries are very complex and time consuming (and not because they aren't optimized).  The results of this query doesn't need to include the latest info to be valid so an MV can can make the cost of this query infrequent.  [In reality MVs often represent complex subqueries that are referenced by a number of other queries which makes accentuates the frequent vs. infrequent value of the MV.]

Sometimes query types don't match well to Redshift's distributed, columnar nature and just don't perform well.  Again, current-ness of data can be played off against cluster workload and these queries can be run at low usage times.

With all that said I think you are on the right path as I've also been trying to get people to see that many, many queries are just poorly written.  Too often in the data world functionally correct equals done and in reality this is only half done.  I've rewritten queries that were taking 90 minutes to execute (browning out the cluster when they ran) and got them down to 17 seconds.  So keep up the good fight but use MVs as a last resort when compromise is the only solution.

Comment: Hey BIll, that's an interesting story! What was the main improvement that optimized that query -- joins, subqueries, dist/sortkey?

Comment: John, some work on keys but mostly removing a massive loop join from their query.  The query needed to be rethought and implemented in a more efficient pattern.  Inequality joining between a large data table and wide ranges of joining were not necessary, just the common patterns.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I appreciate and understand your remarks.  The fact that these aren't arbitrary or particularly complex queries in that they are all aggregates over various time units gives me some hope that optimization can eliminate the need for MVs.  Anyway, I'll give it a try and report on the results.

Comment: Good luck.  Remember that sort keys can really reduce the amount of data scanned from disk and that dist keys impact network transfer during the query.  DistStyle All can also be a big help for dimension tables that are aligning on the dist key of the fact table.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein If you are interested in seeing this kind of speed changes for two logically equivalent SQL statements I wrote up the core change I made for this client.  I've used this example in advanced classes and wrote up a white paper.  It comes with all the code if you care to try it out - http://wad-design.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sql_limits_wp.html

Comment: @BillWeiner Whoa, that 256 function blew my mind!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Nah, now of days a recursive CTE does this and is much cleaner.  In a previous life I designed CPUs so binary math comes easy.

Comment: Adding to Bill's point about complex queries, it's not just the query execution time that may be undesirable but the consumption of resources (cpu, memory, io) and locks being held for the duration. If the source tables aren't very volatile or you don't always need the most current data, MVs can be a useful tool.

Comment: Great points.  Massive spill to disk can be a cluster killer.  The IO bandwidth tied up can brown out all other activity